# Issue Json Object and C#

Tags: c#, json

I have this JSON:

```
{
"BTC_BCN": {
    "id": 7,
    "last": "0.00000019",
    "lowestAsk": "0.00000020",
    "highestBid": "0.00000019",
    "percentChange": "0.00000000",
    "baseVolume": "7.27124323",
    "quoteVolume": "36958572.58593949",
    "isFrozen": "0",
    "high24hr": "0.00000020",
    "low24hr": "0.00000019"
},
"BTC_BTS": {
    "id": 14,
    "last": "0.00001512",
    "lowestAsk": "0.00001518",
    "highestBid": "0.00001512",
    "percentChange": "0.00000000",
    "baseVolume": "3.82925362",
    "quoteVolume": "253971.93868064",
    "isFrozen": "0",
    "high24hr": "0.00001525",
    "low24hr": "0.00001495"
   }
 }
```

...With a lot more records.

This is my Model:

```
public class GetInfoCoinsPoloniex
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
    public string lowestAsk { get; set; }
    public string highestBid { get; set; }
    public string percentChange { get; set; }
    public string baseVolume { get; set; }
    public string quoteVolume { get; set; }
    public string isFrozen { get; set; }
    public string high24hr { get; set; }
    public string low24hr { get; set; }
}

public class RootPoloniex
{
    public GetInfoCoinsPoloniex symbol { get; set; }        
}
```

And this my Controller:

```
[Route("api/poloniex")]
[ApiController]
public class PoloniexController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<GetInfoCoinsPoloniex>> GetCoinsPoloniex()
    {
        string Baseurl = "https://poloniex.com";
        string Parameters = "public?command=returnTicker";
        List<GetInfoCoinsPoloniex> CoinsInfoPoloniex = new List<GetInfoCoinsPoloniex>();            

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Passing service base url  
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            //Define request data format  
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync(Parameters);

            //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
            string CoinResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            CoinsInfoPoloniex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GetInfoCoinsPoloniex>>(CoinResponse);

            }

            return CoinsInfoPoloniex;

        }
    }
}
```

And i get this error:

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.

I think my problem is that i'm not propertly handling the JSON structure. Somebady help me please?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The JSON structure is a dictionary/object, you can’t deserialize it into an array as the error says. Try deserializing into a dictionary instead

Comment: Your json declaration is an object not an array. Replace parent parenthesis {} to [] and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a dictionary, The following may work for you

```
CoinsInfoPoloniex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,GetInfoCoinsPoloniex>>(CoinResponse);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. As we say in Colombia, "you have saved the homeland." Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating a bit more on the answer given by @TheGeneral, if you use a bit of LINQ like this,

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,GetInfoCoinsPoloniex>>(CoinResponse).Select( o => new GetInfoCoinsPoloniex() { id = o.Key, ...}).ToList();
```

This will return you a list of GetInfoCoinsPoloniex objects directly from the json.

> Edit:  Can you accept the edit so i can take the dv back. I don't know
>   how, i think by mistake i clicked and didn't realize and but still my
>   apologies bro

Answer (score 0):

Replace `List` with `Dictionary` as follows:

```
Dictionary<string,GetInfoCoinsPoloniex> CoinsInfoPoloniex = new Dictionary<string,GetInfoCoinsPoloniex>();
```

then use as follows:

```
CoinsInfoPoloniex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,GetInfoCoinsPoloniex>>(CoinResponse);
```